# Complex NOT EXISTS MySQL query - To ignore multiple matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Below is a snippet from a large query I am running which performs a search on a table full of products. This snippet excludes certain products from appearing in results unless it's overridden (a tag ID is specified eg.search criteria is made).

Here's a couple of tag ID's and their names:

**Tag ID 576 = 'Santa'**

**Tag ID 123 = 'Christmas'**

So basically the below will exclude all products in the 'tags_gifts_occasion_specific' table unless they have a tag ID of 576 ('Santa').

```
AND NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT * 
    FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific
    WHERE tags_gifts_occasion_specific.tag_id != '576'
    GROUP BY tags_gifts_occasion_specific.gift_id

   )
```

*Simple right....*

But the problem is if the same product is in this table but has a different tag ID applied to it... eg it also is in there for the tag 'Christmas'.

Of course it would be easy to just add 'AND tags_gifts_occasion_specific.tag_id != '123', however the query doesn't know what additional ID's it shouldn't look for - only the one that has been searched for.

I have been playing around with something like the following but unsuccessfuly. I thought I could count the number of occurences of gift_id and if it was already found then ignore any further - any fresh input would be greatly appreciated.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS no_gifts
        FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific
        WHERE tags_gifts_occasion_specific.tag_id != '576'
    HAVING no_gifts < 1
        GROUP BY tags_gifts_occasion_specific.gift_id

    )
```

** FURTHER DETAIL REGARDING ORDER BY BUG **

So the order by bug is as follows. If someone searches for 'wedding' & 'bridemaid' gifts, wedding or bridemaid gifts should be returned with matches for both showed first, then the rest based on popularity. This works for all searches that do not have gifts in the 'tags_gifts_occasion_specific' table.

```
SELECT gifts.affiliate_id, gifts.gift_id, gifts.gift_title, gifts.gift_price, gifts.gift_image, gifts.gift_slug 

FROM gifts 

LEFT JOIN tags_gifts_occasion_specific AS os ON gifts.gift_id = os.gift_id 
LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
LEFT JOIN popularity ON popularity.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND popularity.tag_id = tags.id 

WHERE published = '1' AND in_seekgifts = '1' 
AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '576' OR tags_gifts.tag_id = '340') ) 
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific x WHERE x.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
        AND NOT EXISTS( 
            SELECT * FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific x1 WHERE x.gift_id = x1.gift_id AND ( tag_id IN (576) OR tag_id in (340) ) )
) 

GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC , popularity.popularity DESC, gifts.gift_popularity DESC, gifts.gift_id DESC
```

Live example of results:
http://www.seekgifts.co.uk/wedding_bridesmaid/

What I think is happening is that it can see the products in the top are in the tags_gifts_occasion_specific table for multiple tags and is therefore ordering by the number of times it is found in this table. Not sure how to get round this one?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. How an uncorrelated subquery in `NOT EXISTS` clause can exclude anything from the outer query ? If this uncorrelates subquery returns some rows, then the `NOT EXISTS` clause evaluates to false, and in this case the outer query returns nothing (an empty resultset).

Comment: The rows that are returned from the sub query are products that should be excluded from the main query. The main query selects many products based on certain search criteria and this is a small part of it. Thie point of this table is that certain products & tags are placed here if they should be excluded from results unless that specific tag is searched for. Eg. Anything with the tag 'christmas' will not show up in results even if they match another tag the user has searched. Like if the user searches 'red' red Christmas things should not appear. Does that make more sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there is a table with products, and there is a table with tags for each product.

And the query is expected to skip products that have some tag, and include products that don't have these tags.

---

For example:
**Products**

```
| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME |
|------------|--------------|
|          1 |    Product 1 |
|          2 |    Product 2 |
|          3 |    Product 3 |
|          4 |    Product 4 |
|          5 |    Product 5 |
```

**Tags**

```
| PRODUCT_ID |          TAG |
|------------|--------------|
|          1 |        Santa |
|          1 |    Christmas |
|          2 |    Christmas |
|          3 |        Santa |
|          4 |    Christmas |
|          4 |      Exclude |
|          4 | Dont exclude |
|          5 |    Christmas |
|          5 | Dont exclude |
```

And we want to skip rpoducts, that have tags `Santa` and `Exclude`.
In the above example, we want to skip products 1, 3 and 4, and include products 2, 5.

---

We can do it using the following **correlated subquery**

```
SELECT * from products p
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM tags t
      WHERE t.product_id = p.product_id
        AND t.tag IN ( 'Santa', 'Exclude' )
     )
;

| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME |
|------------|--------------|
|          2 |    Product 2 |
|          5 |    Product 5 |
```

Here is a link to a working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d880d/4

---

**EDIT**

---

An example for your schema

**Gifts**

```
select * from `gifts`;

| GIFT_ID |             GIFT_TITLE |
|---------|------------------------|
|       1 | Red Christmas stocking |
|       2 |     Santa Clause Socks |
|       3 |      40th Birthday Mug |
|       4 |               Red Bowl |
```

**tags_gifts_occasion_specific**

```
select * from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific`
order by gift_id, tag_id;

| TAG_ID | GIFT_ID |
|--------|---------|
|      3 |       2 |
|      4 |       2 |
|      4 |       3 |
|      3 |       4 |
```

---

This query gets all entries from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific`, except these ones for which exists a tag_id = 3

```
select * from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific` x
where not exists(
  select 1 from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific` x1
  where x.gift_id = x1.gift_id
    and tag_id in ( 3 )
);

| TAG_ID | GIFT_ID |
|--------|---------|
|      4 |       3 |
```

---

Now we use the above query to exclude some records from `gifts` table:

```
select * from `gifts` g
where not exists(
  select 1 from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific` x
  where g.gift_id = x.gift_id 
    and not exists(
       select 1 from `tags_gifts_occasion_specific` x1
       where x.gift_id = x1.gift_id
         and tag_id in ( 3 )
  )
);  

| GIFT_ID |             GIFT_TITLE |
|---------|------------------------|
|       1 | Red Christmas stocking |
|       2 |     Santa Clause Socks |
|       4 |               Red Bowl |
|       5 | Red 40th Birthday Vase |
```

---

Here is a link to a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/558422/5

Comment: Thank you very much for this - I think you understand but I have created a SQL Fiddle that replicates my database structure/names so hopefully you can see the problem exactly as it is. Please see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26c4f This currently returns 1 product as it should. If you now additionally insert the values (2,2) on the tags_gifts_occasion_specific insert query you will see the problem. No rows are returned because the gift ID is also in the table for another tag.

Comment: I've appended an example for your schema to the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Many thanks this looks like it's working now. The only problem now is that the final ORDER BY isn't quite right for searches that have multiple products in the tags_gifts_occasion_specific table. Will amend my question with further details at the bottom - thanks very much again for your help and hope we can crack this

Comment: Kordirko - do you have any ideas for the ORDER BY?